# Hanging Sessions in SQL server with NULL values Blocking other processes

Tags: sql-server, connections

My customer has noticed that there are connections that are opened but they never closed and as a result, API requests are getting timed out since they are getting blocked by a "Ghost" Process.

Example in Customer Table:

The process with number 108 blocks another process.By running SP_WHO2 i am getting that:

```
SPID  STATUS     LOGIN  Hostname  BLKBy   DBNAME    Command ....    - PROGRAMNAME
108 - SLEEPING - Auser - .       - .    - DBNAme - AWAITING COMMAND ... (Nothing here).
```

The script that is being blocked is a simple

```
Select Custid, name....
from Customer
Where custid = 1
```

I have thought of bad indexing but there are useful indexes there.

What should i do to examine the problem?
How will i find how these connections are created and not closed?

Comment: It seems the session has an open transaction holding locks. Confirm with `SELECT open_transaction_count FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = 188;`.

Comment: @DanGuzman note that this is only one example, There are multiple of such connections. i am telling customer to run the query now.

Comment: If these symptoms are pervasive, there might be a bug in the app where connections/transactions are not managed properly.

Comment: So, this is not a database problem, but API does not close properly the connections after finishing the transactions, is it the case?

Comment: Correct, assuming `Auser` is the login used only by the API. Importantly, it's the fact the transaction has not been finished (committed or rolled back) that' the problem. It is common to have many sleeping connections (without open transactions) with connection polling.

Comment: okay so the query returned "1". What's the next step to identify? and adding to your comment about "It is common to have many sleeping connections (without open transactions) with connection polling"  Anything to prevent it?

Comment: To avoid the issue, the app code needs proper connection/transaction management (e.g. using blocks). The only thing that can be done on the server is to kill the session, although you need to understand the implications and the problem will likely surface again until the code is fixed.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you so much for the information!

Comment: If the queries been blocked are SELECT queries it might be worth looking into isolation levels.  e.g. with RCSI or Snapshot isolation level readers are not blocked by writers and vice versa.  
Queries that are sleeping for a long time with open transactions are a problem that need to be fixed from the app side.  If you need monitoring for this, I made some changes to DBA Dash recently to make it easier to track issues relating to sleeping sessions with open transactions.  
https://dbadash.com/blog/whats-new-in-2.46.0/

Comment: @DanGuzman is there any way to find which is the query that has created this hang?

Comment: i'd like to see from which module/batch this is from if there's any possibility.

Comment: @VasileiosG, use [DBCC INPUTBUFFER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-inputbuffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [sys.dm_exec_input_buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to view the last request on the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sleeping connection that blocks other queries indicates an uncommitted transaction on the session which holds locks. This can be observed with:

```
SELECT last_request_start_time, open_transaction_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = 188;
```

Long-running transactions on sessions without recent activity suggests a issue with connection/transaction management in the application code or poor application design (e.g. waiting for user action during a transaction). Applications should commit/rollback transactions immediately after completing work as a best practice to maximize concurrency.

The only thing that can be done on the server side is to kill the session, although you need to understand the implications of doing so. The problem will likely surface again until the code is fixed.